# Silverlight 4 EventTrigger Handled

Tags: silverlight, event-handling, eventtrigger

I have two nested Grid (FrameworkElement) items in my application.

```
<UserControl xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">        
<Grid x:name="OuterGrid">
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
           <i:InvokeCommandAction x:Name="TheOuterCommand" Command="{Binding OuterCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Grid x:name="InnerGrid">
             <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction x:Name="TheInnerCommand" Command="{Binding InnerCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Each of the InvokeCommands is attached to a **DelegateCommand** (from the Prism libraries) in the viewmodel.

```
OuterCommand = new DelegateCommand(OuterCommandMethod, e => true);
InnerCommand = new DelegateCommand(InnerCommandMethod, e => true);
```

At the moment, the EventTrigger on *InnerGrid* also triggers the event on the *OuterGrid* due to the **MouseLeftButtonEvent** not being handled at the *InnerGrid* level.

Is there a way I can notify the **EventTrigger** that it is handled and it should not bubble up to the OuterGrid?

At the moment, all I can think to do is have a wrapper FrameworkElement around the InnerGrid that uses an event on the XAML code-behind to set the event to handled. Does anyone have any other ideas?

**---- Edit ----**
In the end, I have included MVVM Light in my application and replaced InvokeCommandAction with RelayCommand. This is now working as I intended. I'll mark Bryant's answer as the winner for giving me the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to pass the event args to the Command and then mark the event handled using the event args. You can do this by following [this example here](http://thatstoday.com/article/1647491/silverlight-commands-hacks-passing-eventargs-as-commandparameter-to-delegatecommand-triggered-by-eventtrigger).

Comment: Thanks, Bryant. How should the command be defined in the viewmodel? MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(???, () => true). How do I then get access to those event args?

Comment: I've only used MVVM Light and Caliburn Micro for commands so I'm not 100% sure. In MVVM Light you would specify a RelayCommand<EventArgs> as the command type and then the method would have the EventArgs as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

We have extended `EventTrigger` by adding dependency property called `IsInner` and then we always set a static flag in the inner `EventTrigger`. The outer `EventTrigger` unsets the flag and returns if the flag was set. That is extremely easy to write and works well.